# Does emmet allow boolean attributes?

Tags: html, shortcut, emmet

When I type the following text into an editor that understands emmet:

```
div.fragment>pre>code.javascript[contenteditable]
```

it expands to:

```
<div class="fragment">
    <pre><code class="javascript" contenteditable=""></code></pre>
</div>
```

Which is almost perfect, except that the boolean attribute shouldn't have the quotes. Is there a way to write the shortcut so that it expands properly like this:

```
<div class="fragment">
    <pre><code class="javascript" contenteditable></code></pre>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of October 2013 this is now possible.

```
input[type=checkbox checked.]
```

Typing a single period (.) directly after the boolean attribute will produce the following output by default:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

If you want Emmet to output the attribute name without the argument e.g.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked />
```

You'll need to add the following key-value pair to the 'html' object in your Emmet user settings (Mac: 'Sublime Text' > 'Preferences' > 'Package Settings' > 'Emmet' > 'Settings - User')

```
"compact_bool": true
```

Comment: As of 2020,  edit VS code's settings.json file.  Set the property `profile.allowCompactBoolean` to true within `"emmet.preferences":{}` .

Comment: @HelloWorldPeace Thank you for that comment! I was trying to use that in "emmet.syntaxProfiles" and it was not working (naturally).

Answer (score 0):

No, Emmet currently doesn’t support boolean attributes. It will require extra effort and syntax upgrade to explicitly specify boolean attributes in abbreviation. You can create an issue for this: https://github.com/emmetio/emmet/issues